# Relative transform

Tags: matrix, game-physics, transpose, mat, physics-engine

I have two rigid bodies: A and B.
At the moment 0 I have their world transform W<sup>0</sup><sub>A</sub> and W<sup>0</sup><sub>B</sub>.
At the moment 1 a phyisics engine (I'm using bullet) changes the rototranslation of A and I have W<sup>1</sup><sub>A</sub>

If the relative position of B respect to A is not changed, how can I compute W<sup>1</sup><sub>B</sub> that is the world transform of B at the moment 1?

Answer (score 1):

W<sub>AB</sub> = inv(W<sup>0</sup><sub>A</sub>) * W<sup>0</sup><sub>B</sub>
W<sup>1</sup><sub>B</sub> = W<sup>1</sup><sub>A</sub>* W<sub>AB</sub>